# Task não é chamada

Tags: c#, task

Pessoal tenho uma api onde seu processamento demora entorno de 6 horas de execução, dessa forma adicionei uma Task.Factory.StartNew com o processamento principal. Assim, quando a alguém chama, ela responde StatusCode 200 e continua o processamento "pesado" com a Task:

```
public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Processar(TarefaViewModel tarefa){
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {                
            var result = ProcessamentoDe6HorasNoBanco();

            // Chama HttpClient e responde para outra api externa:
            RequestPostStatusGerenciador(result, tarefa.Id, Action.Processar); 

        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);

        return await ResponderAccepted("OK");
    }
```

Porém, volta e meia a Task não é chamada eu tenho que reciclar o IIS para voltar ao normal. Suspeito que seja algo relacionado a Cache do IIS. Alguém pode me dar uma luz sobre essa questão? Nas propriedades do Task.Factory.StartNew, como TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning fariam alguma diferença?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o melhor opção para você seria integrar o [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) ao seu projeto.

Primeiro instale o pacote nuget

```
PM> Install-Package Hangfire
```

Na sua classe `Startup` adicione ao método `Configuration`

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("<connection string or its name>");

app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

Para visualizar os jobs executados, você pode acessar o endereço http://localhost:porta/hangfire

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para adicionar um `Job` ao HangFire

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ContabilidadeJobs.GerarLancamentos())
```

O método fica da seguinte forma

```
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
[LogFailure]
public static async Task GerarLancamentos()
{
    //Processamento pesado
}
```

Acredito que com o uso do HangFire, você terá uma melhor acompanhamento da execução dos Jobs executados, inclusive se houveram falhas de execução.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em meu [github](https://github.com/pablotdv/CodingCraftEX06HangFire), tenho um projeto que utilizei o *HangFire*.

Comment: Como vc usa o Hangfire com UseMemoryStorage para executar uma Schedule a cada 30 segundos ?

Comment: Eu não uso o HangFire com dados em memória, a menor unidade que o hangfire implementa de intervalo é o minuto. Dei uma procurada e todos os lugares que encontrei ninguem consiguiu implementar tarefa para executar na unidade de segundos

Comment: Nem com `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)` funciona. Ja nao sei mais o que fazer. Soh executa 1x quando inicia, nao dispara o Schedule no tempo determinado

Comment: da uma olhada nesse meu projeto https://github.com/pablotdv/CodingCraftEX06HangFire, nele uso o hangfire