# Criar Thread para envio de email?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em ASP.Net MVC e quero criar uma thread para enviar emails a cada 30 segundos. Preciso disso, pois meu provedor não permite o envio de muitos emails ao msm tempo, então pensei em criar um `List<String>` para adicionar emails e esse `List` é lido em um `foreach` e recebe um `Thread.sleep(30000)` de 30 segundos para enviar o próximo email, assim, eu acredito que resolveria meu problema.

Como fazer isso, como criar Threads em Asp.Net MVC ?

Comment: Use o HangFire, veja a minha resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/258607/5846

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas vou testar.

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas precisa ter o SQLServer instalado ?

Comment: Existe uma extensão que habilita o HangFire só em memória (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43207027/2221388), no entanto eu nunca usei.

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas onde eu coloco a chamada pra executar o metodo ? Estou colocando no `Startup.cs` mas não funciona. Estou tentando assim: `BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Debug.WriteLine("Hello, world"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` ai pra executar esse Hello World a cada 1 segundo.